# An elevator can carry a maximum of 1575 lb. What is the probability that 10 people will overload the elevator if their weights are distributed.

Tags: probability

Problem: An elevator can carry a maximum of 1575 lb. What is the probability that 10 people will overload the elevator if their weights are distributed according to $N(150,10)$?

I did it like this:

Given information is :

Maximum value to carry an elevator $\hat{P}$ = 1575

Sample size $n$ = 10

Mean = $\mu$ = 150

standard deviation = $\sigma$ = 10

Consider $x$ is an random variable,

then $x$ = $\hat{P} / n$ = 1575 / 10 = 157.5

therefore, Probability that 10 people will overload the elevator is : $P(X > 157.5)$

i.e $P(X > 157.5) = P(Z > (157.5 - 150) / 10)$

= $P(Z > -7.5 / 10)$

= $P(Z > -0.75)$

= 1 - $P(Z < -0.75)$

= 1 - 0.2266

= 0.7734

$\therefore$ Probability that 10 people will overload the elevator = 0.7734

My prof told me that I am wrong, this answer is not correct. Can someone please help me on this? Appreciate your continuous help and support.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the weights of the $10$ people are independent, the sum of the weights again follows a normal distribution. Its mean equals
$$n\times\mu=10\times150=1500,$$
and the distribution is symmetric about the mean, so certainly the probability of the sum of the weights exceeding $1575$ is strictly less than $\tfrac12$, so your answer is certainly wrong.

In fact, the sum of the weights $\bar{X}$ follows a normal distribution with mean and standard deviation
$$\bar{\mu}=n\times\mu=1500\qquad\text{ and }\qquad\bar{\sigma}=\sqrt{n}\times\sigma=10\sqrt{10}.$$
Now for this distribution compute the probability that $\bar{X}<1575$, i.e. compute $P(\bar{X}<1575)$.

---

**Edit:** The standard way to compute such a probability is to normalize the distribution. You have
$$
P\Big(\bar{X}<1575\Big)
=P\Big(\bar{X}-1500<75\Big)
=P\Big(\tfrac{\bar{X}-1500}{10\sqrt{10}}<\tfrac{75}{10\sqrt{10}}\Big),
$$
where $\tfrac{\bar{X}-1500}{10\sqrt{10}}$ follows the standard normal distribution.

Comment: Ok, but I don't know how to find P($\overline{X}$ < 1575) for this. Will I do P($\overline{X}$ < 1575) = 1 - P($\overline{X}$ > 1575) ? Even though I do it, how do I get that? Can u pls help me here?

Comment: I talked to my prof...he replied "Unfortunately wrong. The variance of the weight of each person is 10, so the calculation of $\overline{\sigma}$ is not OK." Can u pls correct this?

Comment: The calculation of $\overline{\sigma}$ is correct. Note that this is the standard deviation, not the variance.

Comment: well my prof said its still wrong.